# C++ portability issue with the function put in fstream.h when passing a numerical value

Tags: c++, file, fstream, put

I have a question about `put` or other derivatives of in `fstream.h`. Can I make sure about portability of the code when I want to simply write something like so:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
typedef unsigned char u8;
int main()
{
   fstream f;
   u8 ch;
   f.open("deneme.txt",ios::out|ios::binary);
   f.put(129);
   f.close();
   return 0;
}
```

When I write `128` into the `put` function (which takes type of char value as parameter) I took an € but for `129`, it is nothing in the text file. I can't see, can't select. Although the cursor appear at the begining of the file, row,col pointer of the notepad interestingly say 1,2

So, there is something but it is not visible. Also according to tutorials, it was same as far as I remember. Can I write between `0` and `255` without portability issues. In order to ensure about that it writes correctly in binary form in all platforms (compilers/operating systems etc.). The cause of my concern is the `char` type whose range of value can change from platform to platform. Is there such a portability issue for put function or Do I have to worry about it in long run?
OK, I know what to do about that topic anymore. Thanks everybody trying to help me.

Comment: I took one look at that code and refreshed the edit page. Paste, select, hit the format button, done.

Comment: Thanks for updating. I will get used to it in course of time :)

Comment: `ios::binary` ... "nothing in the text file". That's your problem, right there.

Comment: No, there is if you give true values such as 0100 0001/65=A. Aren't ASCII characters too represented in binary form? There is no problem for value of 65 which refers to 'A' and there is no problem again when I want to use extented ASCII like 212('Ô').I don't care about if it writes the letters or sembols correctly,even though some parts after 128 doesn't seem, the only thing I want to guarantee is the knowledge of it writes the value given between 0 and 255 correctly in binary form despite the uncertainty of type of signed/unsigned char.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, there are no issue at all. I don't know what OS do you use. But on *nix like OS it is very simple to check that you get what you want. Look at size of file I sure you it will be 1 byte. And if you open it in hex editor you get byte with value 0x81 or 129.

About editors, some modern editor may think that this 129 character is begin of UTF-8 sequence, and it has at least two bytes length and show wrong results. Another not modern editor may think that this is some 8bit local endcoding, but this encoding may not describe character 129, or font used by this editor may not contains such glyph. This is the problems of editors not your program.